# In jacoco test coverage report how to exclude whole packages?? or some specific files?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, jacoco

So here i want to exclude all files of `cc.mekanism.chatconcept.databinding` in my project and here is my file filter:

```
def fileFilter = [
        // data binding
        'android/databinding/**/*.class',
        '**/android/databinding/*Binding.class',
        '**/android/databinding/*',
        '**/androidx/databinding/*',
        '**/BR.*',
        // android
        '**/R.class',
        '**/R$*.class',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/*Test*.*',
        '**/Binding/**',
        'android/**/*.*',
        // kotlin
        '**/*MapperImpl*.*',
        '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
        '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        '**/*Component*.*',
        '**/*BR*.*',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/*$Lambda$*.*',
        '**/*Companion*.*',
        '**/*Module*.*',
        '**/*Dagger*.*',
        '**/*Hilt*.*',
        '**/*MembersInjector*.*',
        '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
        '**/*_Factory*.*',
        '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
        '**/*Extensions*.*',
        // sealed and data classes
        '**/*$Result.*',
        '**/*$Result$*.*',
        // adapters generated by moshi
        '**/*JsonAdapter.*'
]
```

Is there any working way to exclude whole package from test or specific files like in compose we have files like ListScreen.kt, tried all ways but nothing seems working. My gradle version is ***8.0.2.***

tried adding package like:

```
 cc/mekanism/chatconcept/databinding/**
```

but this also doesn't work.